# Easy way to convert blockcaps to camelcase in Studio?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010

I have a bunch of C defines that I need to port to C#. The C defines are in block caps with underscores, .Net enums should be camelcase.

Any way of converting them automatically? Some tool I'm not aware of, or a magic regex perhaps?

eg.

`BOOTSTRAP_NOT_SUPPORTED`   ->   `BootstrapNotSupported`

Comment: You could use resharper to enforce the naming conventions. I do not think regex will help you as it has no logic to determine camel casing.

Comment: In Perl you could do things like `s/([A-Z\d]+)_?/ucfirst lc $1/ge;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import your defines into your `C#` project and by using [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) you will be able to refactor and rename it quickly and accuratly.

Comment: There is hardly any refactoring. These are entity model property names imported from the database. Most only occur once, but there are hundreds. I don't see how ReSharper would help.

Comment: may be, I think changing the name of entity properties where it is defined will give you ability to re-factor it.(I didn't it before)